# In a time varying magnetic field why is the current flowing through a conducting wire connecting two points of a closed conducting loop zero?

Tags: current, electromagnetism, magnetic-flux

In a Time Varying Magnetic Field like the one shown in the picture below,

[image]

if we connect two points on the closed conducting loop using a conducting wire, why is the current flowing zero ?

My textbook says something like "the emf and the potential drop across the connected points will cancel each other out". But I could not understand the meaning of the statement. Can someone please clarify ?

Comment: Are the magnetic field lines closed around the conductor? Think about it.

Comment: And that's why there's no current. A current would imply the majority of field lines encircled by the loop coming out of the paper (as the field lines outside of the circle outnumber them in any case.)

Comment: No. Current and magnetic field are tied together. You cannot have one without the other. When a current was flowing through the loop, you had field lines going into the paper outside and coming out of the paper inside (or vice versa). That means, when there isn't such a field arrangement, there is no current. Regardless whether the global field is changing or not.

Comment: According to your picture with equal flux lines totally surrounding the coil, there will be no induced voltage and no induced current no matter how much those equal flux lines changed in amplitude.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Cut the loop in half with a horizontal conductor as you have drawn the picture.  Now cover the top half and draw your arrows showing the current in the bottom half.  Now cover the bottom half and draw the top half arrows.  Now uncover the whole thing.  What happens to the arrows on the horizontal conductor?.  Got it?

Answer (score 0):

**Superposition Theorem:** The total current in any part of a linear circuit equals the algebraic sum of the currents produced by each source separately.

[image]

Let resistance per unit angle subtended at the center (in radians)  of conducting loop be \$\lambda\$.

Total EMF (\$E_{total}\$ ) around a circular path in a TVMF is \$ \dfrac{d\phi}{dt}=A \dfrac{dB}{dt} \$ (where \$A\$ is the area of the circle)

We join points A and B on the loop. Suppose AB subtends an angle \$\theta\$ at the centre C.

Now considering only minor arc :

\$E_{AB,minor}=\dfrac{E_{total}\theta}{2\pi}\$

\$i_{AB,minor}=\dfrac{E_{total}\theta}{2\pi \lambda \theta}=\dfrac{E_{total}}{2\pi \lambda }\$

\$E_{AB,major}=\dfrac{E_{total}(2\pi-\theta)}{2\pi}\$

\$i_{AB,major}=\dfrac{E_{total}(2\pi-\theta)}{2\pi \lambda (2\pi-\theta)}=\dfrac{E_{total}}{2\pi \lambda }\$

Now, in the connecting wire AB currents \$i_{AB,major}\$ and \$i_{AB,minor}\$ are in opposite direction and cancel each other out, giving a net current of \$0\$ in the wire.

Comment: Well, yes. Hypercomplicated. For practial exam questions, count the deviant field lines included in the circle. When they are in majority, there is a current. When they aren't, there's no current.